# call a function after completion of previous function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to achieve this:

```
function doThis()
{
    firstFunction(function()
    {
        closeWindow();// close window only after firstFunction() completes
    });
}
```

where doThis() is called from a button. The firstFunction() is an AJAX call after the completion of which second non-AJAX function alert() has to be called. Somehow the code doesnt work as intended. The firstFunction() works and is being called fine. But window.close doesnt seem to be called.

Any advice guys ? No jquery codes please.

**update**:

---

let me elaborate this a bit. the function doThis() is being called from a submit link.

```
<a href="#" name="sumbit" onClick='doThis()'><img src="img.png"/></a>
```

After the press of this link, the form needs to be submitted and this popup windows needs to be closed. firstFunction() POSTs this form using XMLHttpRequest and is working fine when i use it like this:

```
<a href="#" name="sumbit" onClick='firstFunction()'><img src="img.png"/></a>
```

Using doThis() i am trying to post the form first and then only close the form popup but havent been able to.

**update 2**

---

as delnan mentioned,turns out that firstFunction wasnt calling the function that was passed to it as an argument. made these changed and it works well now:

```
function firstFunction(callback)
{
//do ajax stuff
callback(); //calls closeWindow()
}
```

thank you guys !

Comment: You realize that you are passing a function to `firstFunction`, which does nothing unless of course `firstFunction` calls it?

Comment: Open the error console of your browser to see if there are any errors during execution. Post the source code of `firstFunction`. When you notice a difference between your expectations and the actual result, you should mention not only your expectations, but also the actual result.

Comment: could you show us the implementation of the ajax function?

Comment: @Oswald the firstFunction is being called and works fine. But after that, the second function isn't called. There are no errors in the console- i've updated my problem above.

Comment: @gion_13 pls see the update above. the ajax function works great when called alone but i haven't been able to call another function right after the completion of ajax function so that there is no toe stepping.

Comment: @delnan thanks, that was the problem - firstFunction() wasnt calling the function that was passed to it as an argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you positive that your AJAX code works correctly. I mean how do you know that, since the callback function is not executed? 
As of invokation itself you can pass just alert without a wrapper function (to firstFunction that is).

Comment: the ajax function did ajax stuff perfectly but i forgot to call the callback function. works well now. see update 2. thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Declare your function like so:

```
function firstFunction(callback) {
     // setup XMLHttpRequest / IE equivalent
}
```

and in the [readystatechange](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#handler-xhr-onreadystatechange) event handler, call the callback:

```
if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     // other stuff
     callback();
}
```

If you are already doing this then you probably have an error somewhere in `firstFunction` and you have to show its implementation.

Or `doThis` is never called.

Comment: hi, firstFunction() works when i call only it inside doThis() but i'm trying to call another function right after the completion of firstFunction()

Comment: @anp: Well as you said, `firstFunction` makes an Ajax call. As this asynchronous, you have to call the function that should be called afterwards in the `readystatechange` event listener of the XMLHttpRequest object. There is no other way (or I still don't get it but I'm quite sure this is what you mean).